# Can a Model constructor be empty in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 'Cost' model in rails.  Something like the following:

```
class Cost < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :cost_type
    has_many :cost_distributions

    attr_accessor :epp

    def initialize()
    end
```

However, in my tests, when I try to create new instance with the empty constructor

```
    cost = Cost.new
```

I get an error: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1).  Why is it ignoring my empty constructor?

Comment: You don't need a constructor unless there's something special you want to add in there. Are you passing a hash to Cost.new? If so you'll need to handle it in your constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow ActiveRecord to do its own initialization since you are essentially overriding the behavior. Just change your `initialize` to this:

```
def initialize()
 super
end
```

However, if you don't supply a constructor at all, Rails lets you create the model without parameters:

```
Cost.new
```

So is your empty `initialize` method doing anything else? If not, its not even needed.

Comment: If your `initialize` function is empty, and only contains 'super' then it should be working. I tested locally before posting to verify the solution, and it worked. I am pretty confident there is something else in your code (the part you didn't post) that is causing the error.

Comment: I have removed all methods from my Cost class and it seems that it still is expecting a initialize method with a parameter.

Comment: Are you using nested_attributes? You *must* use initialize(*args) when you use nested attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
def initialize(*args)
  super
end
```

Is the secret sauce.

Answer (score 0):

In general, overriding ActiveRecord's `initialize` method [isn't a very good idea](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/22/using-faux-accessors-to-initialize-values).

If your `initialize()` does "nothing", you don't need it. Just remove it.

```
class Cost < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :cost_type
    has_many :cost_distributions

    attr_accessor :epp

end
```

You will still be able to invoke `Cost.new` (the right initialize method will be provided by `ActiveRecord` itself, if you don't override it).